# How can I test Apollo Server subscriptions using jest?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I was using apollo-testing-library for writing integration tests, It allows me to mutate and query but not subscribe and test. My question is, does anyone have any techniques they have used or know a way to mock a subscription using Jest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm definitely late to the party, and this is not a clear answer. But going through the same hurdle myself I thought someone could find this useful.

My solution ended up being an **End-to-End** test of subscriptions.

Meaning I:

- Boot up my existing graphql server
- Create an apollo client in node
- Create subscriptions in my test

I've written a sample gist here:

https://gist.github.com/patrixr/2536ee396d488bd5e38b0278513eefeb

Comment: I need to do this as well and am considering `superwstest` (https://github.com/davidje13/superwstest#readme) since my query/mutation tests are already using `supertest`. Did you look into that at all? I like your approach of using the actual ApolloClient but it feels like more setup.

Comment: @jamis0n didn't know about `superwstest`, could be an option. You're right that setting up Apollo is a big setup, but it paid off in the end as we're able to test the server with the same stack that's running on the frontend.